# SQL Finding duplicate values in two of the three columns of each row

Tags: sql, mariadb

Let's say we have three columns: A, B, and C.

I would like to filter the results as follows:

[image]

The values of A and B are the same (duplicated) for > 1 (more than 1) row, and the value of C is always different.

In the attached image, the values that appear selected would meet the conditions mentioned above.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
  a.notation as A, a.gene as B, b.id as C
FROM 
  `db-dummy`.sgdata c 
  join `db-dummy`.g_info a on a.rec_id = c.gen_id 
  join `db-dummy`.spec_data b on b.rec_id = c.spec_id GROUP BY A, B HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I thought that using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` I could get the desired result, but I get the following error:

> SQL Error [1055] [42000]: (conn=1632) Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db-dummy.b.spec_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a single table, I would suggest just using `exists`.  But because you have a `join`, use window functions.  If you are. looking for *different* values of `id`:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM (SELECT a.notation as A, a.gene as B, b.id as C,
             MIN(b.id) OVER (PARTITION BY a.notation, a.gene) as min_id,
             MAX(b.id) OVER (PARTITION BY a.notation, a.gene) as max_id
      FROM `db-dummy`.sgdata c JOIN
           `db-dummy`.g_info a 
           ON a.rec_id = c.gen_id JOIN
           `db-dummy`.spec_data b 
           ON b.rec_id = c.spec_id
     ) x
WHERE min_id <> max_id;
```

If you are just looking for multiple rows for a given `A` and `B`, then you can use:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM (SELECT a.notation as A, a.gene as B, b.id as C,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.noation, a.gene) as cnt
      FROM `db-dummy`.sgdata c JOIN
           `db-dummy`.g_info a 
           ON a.rec_id = c.gen_id JOIN
           `db-dummy`.spec_data b 
           ON b.rec_id = c.spec_id
     ) x
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I used the second approach, worked like a charm. Could you explain a little bit what is `x`? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Cheknov . . . `x` is a table alias.  MariaDB (and many other databases) require table aliases for derived tables in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `db-dummy`.sgdata a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(Id) as count, notation, gene
FROM `db-dummy`.sgdata
GROUP BY notation, gene
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) b
on a.notation = b.notation AND a.gene = b.gene
```